# python flask: append to form if request.method == 'POST'

Tags: python, mongodb, forms, flask, python-requests

I have a html form and on post, I can pass the form into mongodb

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
        new_employee.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())
```

This works... But how would you append additional string when form is post

for example

```
if request.method == 'POST': 
        employee_username = (request.form['employee_first_name'] + '.' + request.form['employee_last_name'])

        new_employee.insert_one(request.form.to_dict())
```

How would you append for example 'employee_username' : employee_username

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below :

```
if request.method == 'POST': 

        post_data = request.form.to_dict()
        employee_username = (request.form['employee_first_name'] + '.' + request.form['employee_last_name'])
        post_data['employee_username'] = employee_username
        new_employee.insert_one(post_data)
```